# Assigning indexes across rows within python DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently trying to assign a unique indexer across rows, rather than alongside columns. The main problem is these values can never repeat, and must be preserved with every monthly report that I run.

I've thought about merging the columns and assigning an indexer to that, but my concern is that I won't be able to easily modify the dataframe and still preserve the same index values for each cell with this method.

I'm expecting my df to look something like this below:

[Sample DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwfIL.png)

I haven't yet found a viable solution so haven't got any code to show yet. Any solutions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is each column split out by month? What is the need / rationale behind the structure you're looking for?  I would think that moving to a 3-column structure - index, value, modifier (i.e. month, etc.) would make the most sense.

Comment: Yeah so the all the columns are for appointment dates, the rows are clients, and the row indexes will uniquely identify each appointment. Monthly reports will filter for all appointments in the previous month.